# wine - Can I get SWTOR to use backslash and AltGr in keybinds?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, wine, playonlinux

I usually play SWTOR on Windows (10), but being able to play on linux would be so much better for too many reasons to list (and beyond the scope of this question). So I've set it up via playonlinux (using wine version 1.8-staging as recommended by a friend).

Some of my keybinds have changed, however. On windows, I have one keybind as backslash ('\') which I use incessantly, and several more as AltGr+, for example AltGr+K, L, Y and so on. These work fine on Windows.

However, when I load SWTOR on linux - having installed the EXACT same keybind/interface files (and I know it found them because my chatbox and interface are exactly as they should be, which they weren't before I transferred those configs) - the slot which should be bound to \ is now bound to #. Attempting to bind it back, I found that it won't even register \ in the binding dialog box. However, I can easily type backslashes into chat messages, and I can confirm from xkey that the keypress is sent to SWTOR.

A similar story with AltGr: using AltGr+F actually invokes the keybind associated with F, and attempting to bind it back just binds it to F instead. I can't check by typing it in chat, but I verified with xkey that the keypress is sent to the window by X. The bindings are still listed with Ctrl+Alt+F, and indeed I can invoke it like that (it's just how it comes up on windows).

The weirdest thing about this is that it automatically rebound the \ binding to #, with no editing of configs and no manual rebinding (and that I can still type \ into chat, so it's clearly receiving the keypresses). And yet it works fine on Windows.

Can anyone shed any light on where these problems are occurring and what might help fix them?

I'm running playonlinux 4.2.10 installed from the official website, using the SWTOR script listed when you search for it and the installer from the official swtor.com website. My system is

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.3 (jessie)
Release:    8.3
Codename:   jessie
$ uname -srviopm
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4 (2016-02-29) x86_64 unknown unknown GNU/Linux
```

I have a nvidia 940M graphics card (Optimus) which is used by SWTOR via bumblebee (installed from backports, as is the driver).